# 2 sql statements separating

Tags: php, mysql

is it possible to have 2 different sql statement in php? i mean like for example

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "tsukishiro";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT student_no FROM grades_tbl2 WHERE student_no ='C2012-02918'";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM grades_tbl2 WHERE student_no ='C2012-02918' ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row["student_no"]."</td><td>".$row["last_name"]." ".$row["first_name"]." ".$row["middle_name"]."</td><td>".$row["subject_code"]."</td><td>" .$row["subject_desc"]."</td><td>".$row["trans_final"]."</td><td>".$row["remarks"]."</td><td>".$row["subject_prof"]."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

so i want to separate the distinct statements so that the other sql statement does not distinct like the first one. can you help me? so new for this

Comment: you can have 2 (or N) statements on a single connection being executed one after another but not on a single query. You need to send a query per statement.

Comment: so should i make two <?php> codes? or i'm sorry i dont really get what you're saying :((. can you please do some codes in here? :( really need that :/

Comment: Nope. You do `$sqlA = "SELECT DISTINCT student_no FROM grades_tbl2 WHERE student_no ='C2012-02918'";` and  `$sqlB = "SELECT * FROM grades_tbl2 WHERE student_no ='C2012-02918' ";` and you get two different result sets, one for query A: `$resultA = $conn->query($sqlA);` and one for queryB: `$resultB = $conn->query($sqlB);`

Comment: If you want only one result set you need to figure out the SQL for getting the result set that you want on a single query. On extreme cases you might need a stored procedure or filtering the result set on your PHP script, but that is usually an indicator of poor DB design and in that case you should reconsider a different structure, specially if you are on the early stages of development.

Comment: what is it exactly that you are trying to achieve with your two queries? What is the result set you want?

Comment: and, more importantly: what is your current schema? how are your tables arranged? a `SELECT *` doesn't give any clues on what you want to retrieve from the table. Be more specific

Comment: Your first query, for example, will always return a single row with a single column (`student_no`) with the value `C2012-02918`. Which you already have (it's part of your where clause). That makes no sense.

Comment: so should i make my row  `while($rowA =resultA->fetch_assoc()){ ` and `while($rowB=resultA->fetch_assoc()){` or not?

Comment: If you are dealing with two queries, then yes (but it's `while ($rowB=resultB...`). But why do you have that first query?

Comment: i try to make the first sqlA (distinct statement) to be outside of the table and the sqlB in the table i just copied the code for the sqlB(select statement ) table(html) so should i delete the while `($rowA = resultA->fetch_assoc()){` ? then what is the exactly code for my SqlA(distinct) ? i need it so badly :(

Comment: What is your problem with just using the second query? What do you think your first query is for?

Comment: i just want my the first query to distinct / display only one student no ex. i have grades that have the same student no. so i just want to display only one student no. and the 2nd query works for that grades dat will need to list all the grades without the same student no all over again so i just need to separate it

Comment: Think again about what you are doing. It seems to me you just need the second query.